Align equation to first row of matrix
I would like to format a matrix equation, such as
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
A=&\left.\begin{matrix}
\phantom{+}a+b+c\\
d+e+f\\
g+h+i\end{matrix}\right\}\text{first terms}\\
&\left.\begin{matrix}
+j+k+l\\
+m+n+o\\
+p+q+r\end{matrix}\right\}\text{second terms}
\end{align*}
\end{document}

I would like to vertically align the equality $A=$ with the first row of the first matrix. I can't use vphantoms within the matrix, because the braces on the right hand side will include them. Is there a simple way to accomplish this?


Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at our starter guide to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

If you use mathtools, then \mathllap{A={}} should be added before \phantom{+} (why?) on the first line. (untested)

Your idea is good, but needs improvements.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\hphantom{A=}
&\left.\begin{matrix}
\mathllap{A=}\mathbin{\phantom{+}}a+a+a\\
{}+a+a+a\\
{}+a+a+a\end{matrix}\right\}\text{first terms}\\
&\left.\begin{matrix}
{}+a+a+a\\
{}+a+a+a\\
{}+a+a+a\end{matrix}\right\}\text{second terms}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}

The first \phantom makes the centering of the whole thing exact. The second one should be marked \mathbin and in the following lines {}+ provides for correct spacing.
Note the absence of {} after =.


Thanks, that's great!

@daleif Thanks, that worked great! The phantom is because the terms in my groups actually align horizontally in a natural way. Here's your solution applied to my problem, with the terms altered to show their natural horizontal alignment:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\left.\begin{matrix}
\mathllap{A={}}\phantom{+}a+a+a\\
+a+a+a\\
+a+a+a\end{matrix}\right\}\text{first terms}\\
&\left.\begin{matrix}
+a+a+a\\
+a+a+a\\
+a+a+a\end{matrix}\right\}\text{second terms}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}


